# Using neocomplcache and clang_complete?

Tags: vim, clang-complete, neocomplcache

I'm trying to make [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) and [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) to play along nicely. My problem is that when I open a `cpp`, `c`, `objc` or `objcpp` file I get the following error from *neocomplcache*

```
completefunc=ClangComplete^@^ILast set from ~/.vim/plugin/clang_complete.vim
Another plugin set completefunc! Disabled neocomplcache.
```

clang_complete.vim has the following configuration line:

```
au FileType c,cpp,objc,objcpp call <SID>ClangCompleteInit()
```

My question is if there's a way so that I don't get this error anymore ?  Is there a way I could use `clang_complete` and somehow still have access to let's say `neocomplcache` snippets ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This config fixed the problem (in my Vimrc)

```
if !exists('g:neocomplcache_force_omni_patterns')
    let g:neocomplcache_force_omni_patterns = {}
endif
let g:neocomplcache_force_overwrite_completefunc = 1
let g:neocomplcache_force_omni_patterns.c =
            \ '[^.[:digit:] *\t]\%(\.\|->\)'
let g:neocomplcache_force_omni_patterns.cpp =
            \ '[^.[:digit:] *\t]\%(\.\|->\)\|\h\w*::'
let g:neocomplcache_force_omni_patterns.objc =
            \ '[^.[:digit:] *\t]\%(\.\|->\)\|\h\w*::'
let g:neocomplcache_force_omni_patterns.objcpp =
            \ '[^.[:digit:] *\t]\%(\.\|->\)\|\h\w*::'
let g:clang_complete_auto = 0
let g:clang_auto_select = 0
let g:clang_use_library = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a compatibility [patch](https://github.com/osyo-manga/neocomplcache-clang_complete) for neocomplcache and clang_complete.

Comment: Why isn't it distributed with neocomplcache ? :S